# How to access dictionary parameters with key containing "." (dots) in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

if I have structure like this:

```
parameters = {'key1': {'nested_key2': 'value'}}
```

I know how to access 'value' in Jinja2 template:

```
template data
{{ key1.nested_key2 }}
more template data
```

Can I access in Jinja2 template the 'value' defined in the following structure?

```
parameters = {'some.key1': {'another.nested_key2': 'value'}}
```

This way causing errors about 'some' being not defined...

```
template data
{{ some.key1.another.nested_key2 }}
more template data
```

So how I can access 'value' in last case from Jinja2 template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still access this with dictionary notation in jinja2, so you could use it as `parameters['some.key1'].another.nested_key2`

In your case, there is nothing called `some` defined and as there is a `.` between `some` and `key1` it can't resolve it as any variable.

Another thing is that I would strongly recommend you to use `_` instead of `.` for the `some.key1` to avoid this problem, if it isn't an inconvenience otherwise.